# Is possible to install Mono 3.x on Debian 7 Squeeze?

Tags: linux, mono, debian

I've googled a bit, but i didn't find anything about this: I want to install Mono 3.x on my VPS with Debian 7 Squeeze, is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.
I personally build mono packages for myself to get all the library references right, but I assume there are prebuilt packages somewhere on the net too.